# Reloading a DIV without reloading the whole page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm looking for some info about reloading only a div. So if i was to go from **site.com/?id=index** to **site.com/?id=hi**, it would reload content div, nothing else.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, but you probably have to use `<iframe>`'s.